# how do i loop in command prompt and each time change screen color?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to loop 100 times in command prompt and each time change the console color (with values lying between 0 and 7 used to set the possible colors).

However when I try to use `color %variablename%` I always get the same value.

Here is the code:

```
for /l %i in (0,1,99) do set /a var= %i % 8 & color %var%
```

The output form the line `set /a var= %i % 7` is right, that is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,.......`

However, when I call `%var%` on each loop, instead of displaying different results each time it always displays the same one, thus the color changes only once and remains the same for the whole loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use delayed expansion or integrate `Call` to force the variable to update.

Comment: `for /l %i in (0,1,99) do set /a var= %i % 8 & call color %var%`, but be sure that `var` variable does _not_ exists before...

Comment: Do you want to run this in a batchfile or from cmdline?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help guys!

Comment: Gerhard, i'd like it to run it from command line.

Comment: Aacini, I've tried to use the call method and it works, however if i try to use it again with the same variable name it doesn't work, and I have to change its identifier. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

In the command prompt:

```dos
For /F %B In ('"For /L %A In (0 1 99) Do @Set/A %A%8&Echo="') Do @Color %B&Timeout 1 /NoBreak>Nul
```

I put a `1` second `timeout` in there so that you can see the effect, *press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit early*.

Comment: The assignment to `Var=` variable is not needed and may be removed: `@Set /A %A % 8`

Answer (score 0):

batch file, added `timeout /t 1` to display effect, assuming this is what you meant.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (0,1,99) do (
  set /a var=%%i  %% 8
  echo !var!
  timeout /t 1 >nul
  call color !var!
)
```

Comment: Well, the question explicitly specifies (twice!) that the OP wants to do this _from the command prompt_, not in a Batch file... You can easily do the same thing from the command prompt in this way: `cmd /V /C for /l %i in (0,1,99) do @set /a var= %i % 8 ^& color !var! ^& timeout /t 1 ^>nul`

Comment: @aacini the OP clearly specifies cmdline twice, but clearly specifies batch-file tag aswell. I know how to do it in cmdline, i added a start line of "batch file" to give my version based on tag.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer that I intended the comman line, but I can understand the code and found it very useful, thank you! :)